# Red remaining-character counter in SU flag reason unreadable/ugly

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, color

When you flag a post as "requires moderator attention", you get a box to enter a reason. On SuperUser, this box is pink, unlike the red on the other sites. As you type, the number of characters remaining counts down. The first warning level (orange shades, 59-30 characters remaining) is ugly and *somewhat* readable. After this, the red warning is *just plain unreadable*:

*missing image*

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful to illustrate your point.

Comment: You had me at "pink."

Comment: @Kyle Cronin: Thanks for the screenshot.

Comment: Why would this be 'feature-request', and not 'bug'? Is a non-pink dialog a "feature"?

Comment: @Axeman: I agree. I never asked for a non-pink dialog, just that the colors make the text unreadable. Whether changing the warning text color or the dialog color, "unreadable" = "visual bug" in my book...

Comment: I've added the bug tag to the list. Oddly enough I didn't tag it "bug" to begin with so I could be the one to blame. Left the "feature-request" tag, and I'll let a moderator sort the rest out.

Comment: Update: Not sure I'm a huge fan of the incidental white box (looks a little blotchy), but at least it's readable now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I wish we could just get rid of the pink. Next thing you know there will be a pony overlay as a background image.

I feel like @wood was hungry when he designed SuperUser and was chewing on a box of Good & Plenty:

*missing image*

Comment: I like the pink, we just need to tweak some of the other colors (like the red) instead.

Comment: Given the other bright colors, I would assume he was eating Bunny Mix M&Ms left over from Easter: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_mtOUTPEcj20/RggnSsc5gcI/AAAAAAAAAdI/a3Qpcwm-lZE/s400/easter+m&ms.jpg  Those have been sitting out for months, Jeff!